# Resetting My Local Workspace

Tags: tfs, projects-and-solutions

I have a very large TFS project where my local copy's mappings have been screwed up beyond repair. What is the best way to get rid of my local copy and get a new one that will not make the server copy explode or make me have to redo the mapping manually?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you open Source Control Explorer and then open the 'Edit Workspaces' dialog, that will allow you to delete your existing workspace and create a new one.

When you create the new one, you can explictly choose which server paths you want mapped to each local path. You should only have a mapping for directories that you actually need.